# Why doesn't pbpaste return cursor at new line in bash?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

I run the command `pbpaste` in Terminal (bash) to get the result of my clipboard, but unlike other commands which leave the cursor at a new line below the previous stdout, `pbpaste` leaves it to the right of it, as in the example, showing the command sandwiched between two `echo hello`s:

```
hostname:~ jesse$ echo hello
hello
hostname:~ jesse$ pbpaste
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/noizio/id928871589?mt=12hostname:~ jesse$ echo hello
hello
hostname:~ jesse$
```

Why is it like this? It seems very odd and makes it difficult to read.

Comment: What exactly did you copy?

Comment: @Mark The characters in the string on line 4 of my code before "hostname"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pbpaste pastes exactly what you copy.

In your case you have copied the line not including the CR/LF at the end.
To get the return you need to copy from the start of the line to the beginning of the next line

From @patrix comment

Most commands do end with a CR/LF. e.g. `echo "Hello"` will put out a newline, however for echo this can be changed `echo -n "Hello"`.

If you want you can add a newline after a pbpaste by using `echo "$(pbpaste)"` instead.

Comment: So what you're also saying is that almost all other commands with output include a terminating newline?

Comment: @JesseJackson Not directly. `pbpaste` outputs whatever is in the clipboard, which usually doesn't contain a newline. `echo some text` adds a newline by default, but that's something that you can prevent from happening with `echo -n some text`. If you want to ensure a newline after `pbpaste`, use `echo $(pbpaste)` instead.

Comment: @patrix Which other commands don't include a newline by default? I've never seen this behavior in bash before using the pbpaste command.

Comment: @JesseJackson not many but pbpaste is copying that it gets which is need for uses where it is substituted in the middle of a command. As I noted cut and paste usually for me cuts the newline as I copy to the beginning of the line. Also see questions on python without readline

Comment: @JesseJackson The difference is between commands intended to *output* some text in Terminal (like `echo`, `ls` etc.) and commands intended to *return* text/data from somewhere. The former add a newline automatically, the later just return (print) whatever they got (which in case of the clipboard may or may be without a newline).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question about pbpaste specifically, but I'm a user of [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net) (with [oh-my-zsh](http://ohmyz.sh)) and it handles the scenario you describe with the outcome you want for any terminal output.

```
➜  ~ echo -n hello
hello%                                                                          
➜  ~
➜  ~
➜  ~ /bin/bash
bash-3.2$ echo -n hello
hellobash-3.2$
```

I realize it's *bringing out the bazooka to kill a mosquito*, but it solves your real problem where lack of a new line on what you pasted isn't handled gracefully.

Comment: Nice info, even if it is not relevant.